# Recreating the gradient effect inside two div elements

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox, tailwind-css

Long story short, I'm trying to create a wallpaper generator, in which we select two colors, we set the page background to the gradient, and we have two 'cards' or div elements that also have the gradient. Something like below:

[image]

I am stuck with the div/'card' elements in the center and the way they're implemented, currently, I'm having this

```
    <div className="absolute left-[50%] top-[50%] translate-x-[-50%] translate-y-[-50%]">
      <div className="relative w-[300px] h-[300px] bg-blue-700">
        <div className="rectangle1 absolute left-0 top-0 w-[200px] h-[200px] border-6 "></div>
        <div className="rectangle2 absolute bottom-0 right-0 w-[200px] h-[200px] border-6 "></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

The idea is that the cards also have the gradient effect applied going from the top card all the way to the bottom card (it should be one gradient on two cards).
But I have no idea how to have the gradient ONLY at the top level element (the parent of the two div elements) and how I can blend the gradient effect down to the two div elements. I am using tailwind here but if you have any other way of implementing this, I am all ears :).

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you and happy new year!

Answer (score 1):

If you want a gradient with two colors applied to the parent div and blended down to its child div elements using Tailwind CSS, you can do it like this:

```
<div className="absolute left-[50%] top-[50%] transform-translate-[-50%] translate-y-[-50%]">
<div className="relative w-[300px] h-[300px] bg-gradient-to-r from-blue-700 to-purple-500">
<div className="rectangle1 absolute left-0 top-0 w-[200px] h-[200px] border-6 "></div>
<div className="rectangle2 absolute bottom-0 right-0 w-[200px] h-[200px] border-6 "></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Replace 'from-blue-700' and 'to-purple-500' with your desired starting and ending colors. This code creates a gradient from left to right and applies it to the parent div, blending down to its child div elements.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve your goal where the background of parent element blends into the two cards, the two cards need to have transparent background.

After some researching, I found that there is no simple way to cover an element with another element that is having a transparent background.  Instead, I applied clip-path to rectangle2 to achieve the same outcome.

Side-note:

- border-6 is not a default tailwind class, unless explicitly customised in tailwind.config.js, used border-4 instead.
- As for css for rectangle2, tweak the percentages as you wish if the sizes of the rectangles change

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return ( 
      <div className = "absolute left-[50%] top-[50%] translate-x-[-50%] translate-y-[-50%]" >
        <div className = "relative w-[300px] h-[300px] bg-gradient-to-r from-blue-700 to-purple-500" >
          <div className = "rectangle1 absolute left-4 top-16 w-[150px] h-[150px] border-solid border-4 z-50 border-white " > < /div> 
          <div className = "rectangle2 absolute right-4 bottom-16 w-[150px] h-[150px] border-solid border-4 z-50 border-white " > < /div> 
        </div> 
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// Render
ReactDOM.render( 
  <App / > ,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```css
.rectangle2 {
  clip-path: polygon(0 85%, 15% 71%, 20% 0%, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.3"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```